# How to access list from another class with thread

Tags: python, list, class

I am stuck in accessing the list from another class from my main class. This is not my actual code but an example in order to get help here. My problem is how can I access my_list within First class? I tried different methods but no success.
In my actual code myfunc is triggered when I press GUI button (wxpython) thats why you see event there.
Also if I have third class lets say Third, how can i access my_list in that class

```
from threading import Thread

    class First:
      def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'hello'
      def myfunc(self,event):
        Second(self.var1)

    class Second(Thread):
      def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.my_list = []
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()    # start the thread i.e. run()

        #----------------------------------------------------------------------
        def run(self):
            self.my_list.append(self.var1)
```

Comment: You need a "Second" object (an instance of the class) to access its attributes. You should store the instance created in "myfunc" in an object variable if you want to access something in this instance later.

Comment: i did try obj = Second(self.var1) but obj.my_list was giving error

Comment: Can the thread be causing any issue ?

Comment: if possible can you please share example code

Comment: "obj.my_list was giving error" share a [mcve] of the code and the error. Works fine for me: https://repl.it/@alexmojaki/DeeppinkEmotionalFibonacci#main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from threading import Thread


class First:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'hello'
    def myfunc(self,event):
        Second(self.var1)


class Second(Thread):
    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.var1 = var1
        self.my_list = []
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()    # start the thread i.e. run()

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def run(self):
        self.my_list.append(self.var1)

class Third:
    var = 1
    obj = Second(var)
    print(obj.my_list)
```